# Mamba: "No other packages should be installed to base"

Tags: linux, anaconda

The [mamba documentation](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#mamba-should-be-installed-to-the-base-environment) says:

> ### No other packages should be installed to base
>
> Installing packages other than Conda and Mamba into the base environment is not supported. Mamba must live in the same environment as Conda, and Conda does not support having packages other than Conda itself and its dependencies in base.

I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, as this is different from how I've always set up conda.

Does this mean that from the time I initially install mamba I should only use the base environment for creating other environments? Would I then want to designate some other environment, maybe call it "default," as the one that loads through my linux profile?

### Note

Tags for "conda" and "mamba" don't exist yet. Although this is a sysadmin type question, not programming, I'm wondering if I should post instead to stackoverflow?

Comment: "Does this mean that from the time I initially installed mamba, I should only use the base environment for creating other environments?" - No; It's simply a warning to indicate that Conda does not support having additional packages installed in the base environment. If you clone the environment and use that instead and add additional packages, the way I read that quoted statement, is that it should work although based on the unquoted statement it's unsupport it's equally NOT to work because of those additional packages

Comment: @Ramhound -- I wish I understood what you are saying.

Comment: It’s means conda only works with the base environment

Comment: That's not correct either. I've been using conda extensively for at least 10 years. I think I'll have to post a github issue.

Comment: So are you confused by the quoted statement or are you familiar with Conda and already know the answer? Have you tried a different conda environment as a test?